# Using PySpark integer column as argument

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to parse a PySpark column which has an "=" sign inside. The two functions I've created for this purpose work individually:

```
DF=DF.withColumn("findEqual",instr(columnName,"="))
```

and also when I create a column of **Substring**

```
DF=DF.withColumn("parsedString",substring(columnName,2,18))
```

However, when I combine the two functions:

```
DF=DF.withColumn("parsedString",2,instr(columnName,"="))
```

I receive an error:
**TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'**
The issue seems to be that "findEqual" isn't seen by PySpark as an integer, rather an "integer object".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using functions defined on strings not on pyspark columns, you can convert them using `udf`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def instr (x, s):
    return s in x
instr_udf = lambda s: udf(lambda x: instr(x, s), BooleanType())
DF=DF.withColumn("findEqual",instr_udf("=")("columnName"))
```

and

```py
substring_udf = udf(substring, StringType())
```

I would not recommand using UDFs when the functions already exist in pyspark:

```py
DF=DF.withColumn("findEqual",DF.columnName.like('%=%'))
DF=DF.withColumn("parsedString",DF.columnName[2:18])
```